# How to pre-process string data for linear regression at Python

Tags: python

When I have the string data, I can use 'One hot encoding' and 'Numbers for ordinal data' with panda module.
But in my case, my data is more complicated. So I'll appreciate if you give me some advice.

For example, I have this data with comma. Which method is a good choice for using it in linear regression?

```
    categories
0   shoes, men's shoes
1   Clothing,,All Women's Shoes
2   Boots,Shoes,men's Shoes
```

Additionally, 
I have the data more like below.

```
    price  sales quantity   brand          color
0    100         20          Nike          Black
1    200         25          Adidas        Purple
2    150         60          New Balance   Yellow
3    200         10          Nike          Green
```

And I want to use linear regression to predict sales quantity depends on various data.

Comment: From your question, it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. What exactly is the data you have provided, what are you performing linear regression against (what are you trying to predict?), and what kind of outcome are you trying to achieve? Please edit your question and potentially look at [ask] so that we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you , I edit more about my question, Andrew.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to predict sales quantity using three variables: price, brand, and color, correct?

Comment: price, brand, color and categories also. So I asked how to preprocess categories.

Comment: I can make brand and color as one hot enconding. But I don't know how to use categories value.